# Powershell: Out-File - Access to the path is denied

Tags: rest, powershell, scripting

I've got a REST call (POST) for downloading a PDF file. The API call responds in a binary version of the PDF file. I want to save the file on my machine as a .pdf. However, I am getting an error:

```
Out-File : Access to the path 'C:\Users\my-name\Documents\Tests' is denied.
At C:\Users\my-name\Documents\Tests\TEST-WITH-LOOP.ps1:132 char:149
+ ... questBody | Out-File -FilePath ("C:\Users\my-name\Documents\Tests
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

Response body header from POSTMAN:

```
Content-Disposition →attachment; filename="Report-01_29_14-28.pdf"
Content-Type →application/octet-stream
DataServiceVersion →2.0
Date →Mon, 29 Jan 2018 21:51:31 GMT
Date →Mon, 29 Jan 2018 21:51:31 GMT
Server →Jetty(9.3.7.v20160115NeotysEdition.30)
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
```

Command:

```
$DownloadReportResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $DownloadReportUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Body $DownloadReportRequestBody |
    Out-File -FilePath ("C:\Users\my-name\Documents\Tests") -Force
```

**Question:**
How do I save this to my machine as a .pdf or possibly include as an attachment to the email?

Comment: Isn't the error clear enough? You miss file access rights at folder "C:\Users\my-name\Documents\Tests".

Comment: So what is the solution to have the rights for file access? I am running this script as an Administrator and have the Execution policy set to RemoteSigned.

Comment: Does the used account have even access rights to that folder? Being an admin doesn't grant folder rights to user-specific folders under Windows. Check that. Easier would be to use another (possibly more appropriate) folder, even if it was for testing only so overcome the issue.

Comment: I don't know how to get the information you're suggesting. But I created a new folder in C: directory and no luck. Same error. Maybe the script is looking for the file in the directory and cannot find one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, the error is a bit misleading. You're trying to create the output file as `C:\Users\my-name\Documents\Tests`, but that already exists as a directory, hence the access violation. Create the file with the full path:

```
Invoke-RestMethod ... |
    Out-File "C:\Users\my-name\Documents\Tests\Report-01_29_14-28.pdf"
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, that solved the issue. But when I open the saved file I'm getting an error saying it's not the right pdf file. Maybe there's an issue with decoding the binary file? What do you think? Is there a way to decode the binary pdf file in powershell?

Comment: Depends on what ouput your `Invoke-RestMethod` call actually produces. Capture it in a variable (without piping into `Out-File`) and check the type: `$rsp = Invoke-RestMethod ...; $rsp.GetType().FullName; $rsp | Get-Member`.

Comment: $DownloadReportResponse.GetType(); $DownloadReportResponse | Get-Member is this the right command? Because I am getting You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. error

Comment: You *did* remove the `| Out-File ...` from the `Invoke-RestMethod` call like I told you, didn't you?

Comment: I did, here is my call. $DownloadReportResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $DownloadReportUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers -Body $DownloadReportRequestBody

Comment: Then `Invoke-RestMethod` didn't return any data.

Comment: It returns a binary version of pdf. I just need help decoding the pdf from the response. I don't know if I can send you the Url and the request body so you can see the the data.

Comment: If `Invoke-RestMethod` returned any data, the value of `$DownloadReportResponse` would not be `$null`, and you wouldn't be getting the error you say you're getting. Please edit your question and show the value of `$DownloadReportResponse` and/or the output of your `Invoke-RestMethod` call.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same concern when using the `Out-File` command to redirect output to a file.

My command was this:

```
Out-File -FilePath C:\MyFiles -InputObject "My text"
```

When I run the command I get this error:

```
Out-File: Access to the path 'C:\MyFiles' is denied.
```

The issue was that I was redirecting the output ("`My text`") to a directory and not a file.

I had to modify it this way by specifying the file (`program.txt`):

```
Out-File -FilePath C:\MyFiles\program.txt -InputObject "My text"
```

This time it worked out fine.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**